# All saved variables in $localstorage

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

I am developing an android app using angularjs and Ionic and I use $localstorage service for storing data temporarily in the application. As I've searched I could not find proper way in order to see all the stored variables in $localstorage and I can not decipher it from chrome inspector, is there really a way?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can enable the experimental dev tools features.

You will then get an extra tab in your chrome developer tools.

[image: Dev tools Application tab]

For reference:

- [Application tab in chrome dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/local-storage?hl=en)
- [Enable experimental dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/settings)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

When you Right click on Google Chrome, click on inspect and select console. After that simply write localStorage and enter
it gives you all stored key & value pairs and for storing data in localStorage like this:-- **localStorage.setItem(key, value)**.

But $localStorage is available for angularjs. You can check your localStorage in console like: - console.log($localStorage)

Example:-- [Check Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WkB1.png)